# Angularjs HTML attribute code styling guidelines

Tags: html, angularjs

This is somewhat opinion based, but I was wondering about good practices to styling HTML attributes in code when using Angularjs. As I am sure you know there is a problem of too long lines if there are no lines breaks in between attributes.

This is killing the readability:

```
<input spellcheck="false" type="text" name="some_name" id="some_name" ng-this ng-that long even-longer blablabla>
```

So I tend to do this:

```
<input 
    spellcheck="false" 
    type="text" 
    name="some_name" 
    id="some_name" 
    ng-this 
    ng-that>
```

Any official guidelines on this, or suggestions. Thou the second option is more readable too me, it's still bad in my opinion. Messes me up a bit on elements that have some content or other element in them.

Comment: that's how my codebase does it too

Comment: As always, the best way to do it is the way that you understand the most !